# How to get data from Secure REST API in lambda for Alexa skill?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, web-api-testing

I am creating a Alexa Skill that will get data from BPM tool.

My BPM Tool provide a secure rest api that we can invoke with basic auth like username and password.

How can i call this type of web api  in node.js code created in lambda?

Answer (score 0):

**Steps:**

1) Create Amazon API Gateway api for alexa and deploy into stage

2) Write [lambda to work with Alexa Skill](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-an-aws-lambda-function.html)

3) Call your API end poingt into your node.js

- https://github.com/alexa
- https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about credentials, you can set those up as [environment variables for your lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html).

With that out of the way, you should be able to use any http library (like [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) or [needle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/needle)) to make the requests to the service.